# stuck in build a panel plugin tutorials in grafana

Tags: typescript, grafana

I have follow Build a panel plugin tutorials (https://grafana.com/tutorials/build-a-panel-plugin/)
but i get stuck to add .addRadio on **src/module.ts**

the issue is when i added .addRadio IDE show warning message

```
Property 'addRadio' does not exist on type 'PanelPlugin<SimpleOptions, any>'.ts(2339)
```

and when i force to build a plugins it show

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ grafana-toolkit plugin:dev
⠙ Linting


  /var/lib/grafana/plugins/panel-plugin/src/module.ts
    43:4  error  Parsing error: Declaration or statement expected

  ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)



  Trace: Error: 1 linting errors found in 4 files
      at /var/lib/grafana/plugins/panel-plugin/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/src/cli/tasks/plugin.build.js:98:31
      at step (/var/lib/grafana/plugins/panel-plugin/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:140:27)
      at Object.next (/var/lib/grafana/plugins/panel-plugin/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:121:57)
      at fulfilled (/var/lib/grafana/plugins/panel-plugin/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:111:62)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
      at /var/lib/grafana/plugins/panel-plugin/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/src/cli/utils/useSpinner.js:25:29
      at step (/var/lib/grafana/plugins/panel-plugin/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:140:27)
      at Object.throw (/var/lib/grafana/plugins/panel-plugin/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:121:57)
      at rejected (/var/lib/grafana/plugins/panel-plugin/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:112:69)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
✖ 1 linting errors found in 4 files
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

can anyone explain me what i do wrong or i can actually have .addRadio once at the same time?

**everything works fine when i remove a first .addRadio

here is my **src/module.ts**

```
import { PanelPlugin } from '@grafana/data';
import { SimpleOptions } from './types';
import { SimplePanel } from './SimplePanel';

export const plugin = new PanelPlugin<SimpleOptions>(SimplePanel).setPanelOptions(builder => {
  return builder 
  
    .addTextInput({
      path: 'text',
      name: 'Simple text option',
      description: 'Description of panel option',
      defaultValue: 'Default value of text input option',
    })
    
    .addBooleanSwitch({
      path: 'showSeriesCount',
      name: 'Show series counter',
      defaultValue: false,
    })
    .addRadio({
      path: 'seriesCountSize',
      defaultValue: 'sm',
      name: 'Series counter size',
      settings: {
        options: [
          {
            value: 'sm',
            label: 'Small',
          },
          {
            value: 'md',
            label: 'Medium',
          },
          {
            value: 'lg',
            label: 'Large',
          },
        ],
      },
      showIf: config => config.showSeriesCount
    }); // <=== fixed it by remove this ;

    .addRadio({ // show error when added this
      path: 'color',
      name: 'Circle color',
      defaultValue: 'red',
      settings: {
        options: [
          {
            value: 'red',
            label: 'Red',
          },
          {
            value: 'green',
            label: 'Green',
          },
          {
            value: 'blue',
            label: 'Blue',
          },
        ],
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try changing `});.addRadio` to `}).addRadio`

Comment: that awsome, thx for the help @NadiaChibrikova